# How to publish images of a file.bag on a topic with python?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rospy

I'm a beginner with ROS, so i thank you in advance for your answers.

I have a file.bag (Video) available and I would like to publish the various frames on a specific topic at defined moments of time so that I can view this frame and work on it later.
My question is how can I accomplish this in ROS Melodic with Python?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! As you are getting started with ROS, I suggest using existing ROS packages to achieve this functionality. Following are the steps: 1) [Export images from the bag file](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data), 2) Select the frames you are interested in, and 3) [Publish those frames/images one by one](http://wiki.ros.org/image_publisher).

Comment: Thank you so much @ravi